# How to make segments under lists with mailchimp laravel

Tags: laravel, mailchimp

i am using mailchimp as mailing service with laravel and want to add segment under particular list to send campaign to that specific list/segment

Answer (score 0):

```
MailchimpWrapper::lists()->segmentAdd(
    $this->getList(),
    array(
        'type'=> 'saved',
        'name'=>'testSeg',
        'segment_opts'=>array('match'=>'any', 'conditions'=>array(['field'=>'email', 'op'=>'eq', 'value'=>'architwankhede@gmail.com']))
    )
)
```

Try this